# Break out of for loop after encountering two separate keywords

Tags: python

Say I have a file as below:

```
apples  53 24
apples  23 56
apples  24 98
oranges 10 34
oranges 12 38
```

I want to know if there is a way to print out just the first line containing "apples" and the first line containing "oranges"

Note: The no. of lines containing "apples" and "oranges" may NOT always be the same. So, I cannot specifically go to a line number. But lines containing "oranges" will always follow lines containing "apples"

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Expected Output:

```
apples  53 24
oranges 10 34
```

Comment: This is programming 101. Broken down this requires you to 1. read file. 2. for loop over lines of file. 3. get first word of a string 4. test if first string is 'apples' or 'oranges' (optional) 5. add to dictionary/set/list if not seen 6. print output of dictionary/set/list (just apples/oranges if step 4 skipped). Google each of these steps preceded by 'stackoverflow python' to learn about these

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
with open(file) as fp:
    seen = set([])
    for line in fp:
        token = line.split()[0]
        if token not in seen:
            seen.add(token)
            print(line)
```

Comment: As a side note, you can initialize a set this way `set()`

Comment: Yes, you're right. I got such habit of initializing a `set` from Python 2.5.

Comment: This seems to do the exact job without importing any additional modules. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This is a nice use for [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) so long as you want the first of each group — in other words if there's a another group of apples later in the list, it will print the first of those too (it's not clear in the question if that's possible or what should happen) Given that, this should handle any number groups:

```
from itertools import groupby
with open('test.txt') as file:
    for k, g in groupby(file, key=lambda x: x.split()[0]):
        print(next(g).strip())
```

**result:**

> apples  53 24
>   oranges 10 34

Answer (score 0):

You could use `itertools.dropwhile`!

```
from itertools import dropwhile

with open("...") as f:
    lines = iter(f)
    print(next(lines))  # prints the first line
    print(next(dropwhile(lambda line: line.startswith("apples"), lines)))
```

Comment: Is it hard to change this so that `apples` isn't hard-coded in for cases where there might be more than two fruits?

Comment: Somewhat? You can of course define a function that, given a word, returns a function returning whether a given line starts with that word.